# How would I return JSON properties from an ASHX file when using AJAX to send JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have a from that on submission will send item values to an ASHX file using JSON. I want this ASHX file to take the JSON string and loop through each item. I have placed these in a items object which contains and an array of items. There are several articles on Stack Overflow that describe how you can "deserialize" an array and add this into a custom class, however, I am not sure how this will happen with an array of objects. Could you please also describe this to me as if I am five?

```
 $.ajax({
                url: 'addItems.ashx',
                data: JSON.stringify( {items: objectArray } ),
                method: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data.responseText);
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    console.log(data.responseText);
                }
            });
```

Sample JSON:

`{"items":[{"qty":"374","description":"Non repellendus Illum voluptate ea eu tempora eaque maiores quaerat corrupti rerum distinctio Omnis voluptatem","capAsset":"2","iuTag":""},{"qty":"374","description":"Non repellendus Illum voluptate ea eu tempora eaque maiores quaerat corrupti rerum distinctio Omnis voluptatem","capAsset":"2","iuTag":""}]}`

ASHX File:

```
public class items
{
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string iuTag { get; set; }
    public int capAsset { get; set; }
    public int qty { get; set; }
}

public class addItems : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SurplusConnectionString"].ConnectionString.ToString();  
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";         
        JavaScriptSerializer json_serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
        var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<items>(json);            

    }
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I posted a write-up a while ago about using the JavascriptSerializer class to deserialize objects including some arrays.

http://www.tomasvera.com/programming/using-javascriptserializer-to-parse-json-objects/

It discusses deserializing arrays of objects (in this example it's a menu system) and you may find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You are close - all you need to do now is write the output to the Response using the HttpContext that you receive as parameter:

```
context.Response.Write(jsonString);
```

And I would add the appropriate headers as well, to indicate that you are returning JSON

```
context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/json"));
```

The syntax might be a little off but that's the idea.